# Reinstall apache2 mysql php phpmyadmin

Tags: apache2, php, mysql, reinstall

OK, I am stuck. So I need to reinstall apache2 mysql php (I have php 5.6 and 7.0) and phpmyadmin.
Eny instruction?

Comment: please provide more information, like what did you try, what errors do you get, what caused you to get stuck

Answer (score 0):

try to purge all packages from the system, and just follow this tutorial step by step ..
[How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)

be aware not to purge mysql-common or any related files